# Understand Error in Perl script

Tags: perl, csv, line-breaks

I'm trying to write a Perl script that convert the line endings of some CSV files stored in a folder. I am a Perl newbie so any help would be appreciated.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = glob "*.csv";

foreach my $i (@files) {

    system('perl -i.bak -pe "s/\R/\n/g" '.$i.'') or die "$?";

}
```

After converting the first file the script terminate with this error:

```
0 at script_conversione_linebreaks.pl at line 8.
```

Is it the right way to do the conversion? Or I have to pass all CSV files at once in the system statement?

Comment: First question is - what are you actually trying to accomplish? You mention you're looking to process the files after - there's actually a fairly good chance therefore, that doing a conversion separately isn't necessary.

Comment: @RobEarl's advice is very hepful

Comment: Perhaps using `dos2unix` or similar would be preferable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About your error message, since the return value of `system` is the status of the program, if the program was successful you would get `0`. This means you will `die`, since `0` is interpreted as false.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = glob "*.csv";

foreach my $i (@files) {
    system('perl -i.bak -pe "s/\R/\n/g" ' . $i) and die "$?"; # Note the `and`
}
```

As a further notice: you are running a subprocess for every `csv` file. This is bad in terms of performances. You may want to consider running a single command from your shell:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\R/\n/g' *.csv
```

I believe however this is the kind of situation in which you should choose another weapon.

Does this help?

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.csv; do cp $i $i.bak; dos2unix $i; done
```

*Edit:* as pointed out by @AkHolland in the comment, you could directly call `dos2unix` on all the files at once, and let it cycle on them. This will not generate backups, but it's also true that `dos2unix` will hardly go wrong *on text files*.

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Tnx for the advice. I've never used dos2unix, I will give it a try. By the way I would like to know how to solve the error in Perl execution.

Comment: `dos2unix` wll go badly wrong if you accidentally run it on a file that is not text.

Comment: @cjm, fixed. Also I think a perl one-liner would go wrong as well XD

Answer (score 1):

I would use @Dacav's solution, but the bug in your program is that `system` returns the exit code of the executable that was called, and `0` means success here.

So

```
system "something" or die $?;
```

should really be

```
system "something" == 0  or die $?;
```

Since this is what you want most of the time, Perl has a pragma to automatically check for error codes on `system` and friends:

```
use autodie qw(:all);
```

Add this to your program and you'll get exceptions instead of having to check return codes.

Comment: Interesting `autodie` thing. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

What about one liner perl:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\R/\n/g' path/to/files/*.csv
```

Comment: I need to manipulate the CSV data after the conversion, so I used a script instead of the command line. Tnx.

Comment: If you do that, you probably don't need to convert at all.

Comment: I didn't find a solution to read the not converted CSV file line by line. It was read as a whole string.

Comment: Try change the input record separator: `$/ = "\R";`

Comment: @RobEarl tnx. This is a very useful.